# how to write a log file when message is sent to remote mq

Tags: ibm-mq

I want to write a log file in c#. Everytime a message is coming to remote mq . example : suppose abcd message is sent to remote mq then log file will record that like 1 message is received in remote mq at 10-09-2018 11:30 am with time and date entry. how can i achieve this. Is it possible to write this kind of code ? any clue,any idea ,any link will be helpful. Please help.

**EDIT**

```
        MQQueueManager queueManager;
        MQMessage queueMessage;
        MQGetMessageOptions queueGetMessageOptions;
        MQQueue queue;


        string QueueName;
        string QueueManagerName;
        string ChannelInfo;
        string channelName;
        string PortNumber;
        string transportType;
        string connectionName;

        QueueManagerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QueueManager"]; 
        QueueName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Queuename"];
        ChannelInfo = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ChannelInformation"];
        PortNumber = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"];
        char[] separator = { '/' };
        string[] ChannelParams;
        ChannelParams = ChannelInfo.Split(separator);
        channelName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Channel"];
        transportType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TransportType"];
        connectionName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionName"];
        String strReturn = "";

        try
        {
            queueManager = new MQQueueManager(QueueManagerName,
            channelName, connectionName);
            strReturn = "Connected Successfully";

            queue = queueManager.AccessQueue(QueueName,
            MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
            queueMessage = new MQMessage();
            queueMessage.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
            queueGetMessageOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions();
            queue.Get(queueMessage, queueGetMessageOptions);
            strReturn = queueMessage.ReadString(queueMessage.MessageLength);
        }
        catch (MQException exp)
        {
            strReturn = "Exception: " + exp.Message;
        }

        string path1 = @"C:\documents\Example.txt";
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path1, strReturn);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your exact problem with writing the log file?

Comment: I can connect to remote mq and after connecting I can save the message into text file but I want to write that message is received before downloading the msg

Answer (score 0):

This question has nothing to do with MQ.  It is simply a basic C# programming question.  There are lots of logging frameworks for C# that you can use.

Here are 2 basic methods for logging in C#.  Create your own "Logger" class and put them in it.

```
public static void WriteLog(String logFileName, byte[] data)
{
   FileStream fs = null;
   DateTime currentDT = DateTime.Now;
   String header = currentDT.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + " ";
   String LF = "\n";

   try
   {
      fs = new FileStream(logFileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);

      if (fs.CanWrite)
      {
         fs.Write(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(header), 0, header.Length);
         fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
         fs.Write(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(LF), 0, LF.Length);
      }
   }
   catch (IOException ex)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
   }
   finally
   {
      try
      {
         if (fs != null)
            fs.Close();
      }
      catch (IOException ex)
      {
         Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
      }
   }
}

public static void WriteLog(String logFileName, String data)
{
   FileStream fs = null;
   StreamWriter sw = null;
   DateTime currentDT = DateTime.Now;
   String header = currentDT.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + " ";
   String LF = "\n";

   try
   {
      fs = new FileStream(logFileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);

      if (fs.CanWrite)
      {
         sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
         sw.Write(header);
         sw.Write(data);
         sw.Write(LF);
      }
   }
   catch (IOException ex)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
   }
   finally
   {
      try
      {
         if (sw != null)
            sw.Close();
      }
      catch (IOException ex)
      {
         Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
      }

      try
      {
         if (fs != null)
            fs.Close();
      }
      catch (IOException ex)
      {
         Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
      }
   }
}
```

Then in your MQ application, after a successful get of a message from a queue, you can do the following to log it:

```
Logger.WriteLog("C:\temp\mylog.txt", "message received");
```